# Tutorial to Set Up Isomorphic SSR with Ejected Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering, isomorphic

I have unsuccessfully found a tutorial for setting up isomorphic server side rendering with an **ejected** [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

I know of [react SDK](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-app), but this isn't ejected, and there are quite a few tutorials on non-ejected created react apps.

Could anyone help locate one, or link to a project that is an example of ejected app now an isomorphic SSR? Ideally without redux for simplicity.

[webpack-isomorphic-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-isomorphic-tools) provides clues but it really doesn't do much more than that.

Comment: What is an *exploded* app? Do you mean **ejected**?

Comment: Wow that was a fail, yes I meant ejected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Paragons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-paragons). It's a great Universal React SPA starting point. Plus it has Code Splitting all ready to go, SEO support, Sass, React Router v4, and much much more...

Comment: took a bit of setup, they forgot to mention you need to `npm i -g yo npx`, but works like a charm! Thank you @dan

Comment: `npx -p yo generator-paragons my-app` should do the trick too and that way you don't have to install `yo` globally.

Answer (score 1):

you can check this on 
it is being ejected
https://github.com/agungsb/create-react-app-ssr-pwa